# How to detect google calendar in local EventStore

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, calendar

In setting of iPhone, I was login the google calendar.
I program an iPhone app, that can detect the event that is belonged to the logged in google calendar as above.

```
EKEventStore* eventStore;
eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
NSPredicate* predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:firstDate endDate:lastDate calendars:eventStore.calendars];
NSArray* fetchedEvents = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
for(EKEvent* ecEvent in fetchedEvents)
{
   // How to do
}
```

1. How can I do that?
2. I also research but almost have to:

Method 1: program for user choose an calender (include google calendar)

Method 2: program for get default calendar (may be that is google calendar)

Method 3: program a app that login and get google calendar as same as [Using Google Calendar Api in iPhone](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-requests/49249-using-google-calendar-api-in-iphone-app.html) have other method.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Re: question 1, this will tell you if the event belongs to a google calendar:

```
EKCalendar *calendar = event.calendar;
if ([[calendar source] sourceType] == EKSourceTypeCalDAV &&
    [[[calendar source] title] isEqualToString:@"Gmail"])
    NSLog(@"found a Gcal event");
```

Sometimes (if there are multiple google accounts configured) `[[calendar source] title]` will return the gmail address instead of @"Gmail", so you may want to check for that as well.